# Why does the correlation depend linearly on the angle, in the classical case of Bell experiments?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, probability, correlation-functions, bells-inequality

I am struggling to understand why we would predict the decay in correlation between the two measurements in a Bell Inequality experiment to be linear (see red line in this image from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem)). I understand there is a max and min, that seems obvious. But why should we assume the function between those two points will be linear in the classic scenario? many thanks
[image]

Comment: what are you referring to exactly? Can you add a reference to the post, as well as the equations you are presumably thinking of?

Comment: Thanks , I have now added an image. I am referring to what the 'expected result' looks like as shown by the red line. Why would it be linear between the min and the max and not any other shape?

Comment: I see what you mean now. I edited the title in an effort to make it clearer. I think it's a good question as it stands now

Comment: thanks, nice title!